# Magento 2: How to add a Color Picker in Grid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, color-swatches, editor

I'd like to add the standard Magento color picker to a custom grid in the admin panel, as an editable field. I have been able to do this in admin forms using code like the below, but have no idea how to get it to render a color picker in a UI-component grid as opposed to a form?

The UI component seems to require all arguments to be javascript, but the devdocs refer to a **color picker** element which doesn't actually exist in **Magento_Ui/js/form/element**:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-inline.html

My code below works in a form, just want to do something similar in a custom admin grid!

Thanks for any help!

BLOCK:

```
<?php
namespace Duel\Gallery\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param array $data
 */

public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
    $html = $element->getLabelHtml() . $element->getElementHtml();
    $value = $element->getData('value');

    $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                // Attach the color picker
                $el.ColorPicker({
                    color: "'. $value .'",
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
    return $html;
}
```

}

FORM:

```
$colourpickerRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Duel\Gallery\Block\Color'
    );
    $field1 = $fieldset->addField(
        'duel_colour',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'duel_colour',
            'id' => 'duel_colour',
            'title' => __('Colour'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );
    $field1->setRenderer($colourpickerRenderer);
```

In the Grid Listing ui component my columns are laid out as below - for custom component like "select" it seems to expect a javascript based component from the Magento_Ui folder - not sure how to pass my own component (which would include the color picker) in this way? Or should I try and add the javascript mentioned in the answer below to the head of the page?

```
<column name="gallery_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gallery ID</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="duel_rows">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Duel\Gallery\Model\Config\Source\DuelRowsAndColumns</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rows</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="duel_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Duel\Gallery\Model\Config\Source\DuelRowsAndColumns</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Columns</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="duel_colour">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Colour</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep below content instead of your ,

```
$html .= '
        <script>
            require([
            "jquery",
            "jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker",
            "domReady!"
            ], function ($) {
            var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                // Attach the color picker
                $el.ColorPicker({
                    color: "'. $value .'",
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
```

In my "listing" ui component the columns are like below - not sure how to pass custom javascript to one of these columns to include the color picker?

```
<column name="gallery_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gallery ID</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="duel_rows">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Duel\Gallery\Model\Config\Source\DuelRowsAndColumns</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rows</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="duel_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Duel\Gallery\Model\Config\Source\DuelRowsAndColumns</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Columns</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="duel_colour">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Colour</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what is the best way to include the custom javascript? As I don't have a block file (unlike when using forms). My "grid" columns are as above at the moment: